# ZK Framework: notify ViewModel from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, mvvm, zk

I have a ZK MVVM application with a standard UI bound to a ViewModel and one additional servlet for communication with an external app. I need to do the following: when the additional servlet receives a http request, I need to notify the ViewModel and display some data to the user via server-push.

I tried to notify the ViewModel from the servlet via a GlobalCommand by calling `BindUtils.postGlobalCommand` and also via an event queue using `EventQueues.lookup` but in both cases, I get an IllegalStateException with message: Not in an execution.

I also tried to keep a reference to the ViewModel in the servlet and directly calling its method, in which the ViewModel tried to call `BindUtils.postNotifyChange` but I got the same result.

Is there some way I can achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Actually, all users accessing the site should get the notification. The servlet does change data in a database and the viewmodels display the data but the idea is to let the viewmodels know when and especially WHAT has changed, so they can notify the users about the change. I could make the viewmodels check the database regularly but I'd somehow have to remember the previous state and implement a complex comparison algorithm to find out what has changed.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to do. You could look into application-wide EventQueues http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Queues

Comment: As I stated in the question, I tried to use EventQueues but in order to publish something in the queue I need to retain it with EventQueues.lookup, which gives me the described InvalidStateException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you should review your architecture. But for the sake of the answer you could use the [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) java built-in pattern.

You can create a service (assuming you are using Spring) which extends Observable. Then you declare a Window to implement the Observer pattern and to enable the server push on his desktop. Last but not least you register the Window (the observer) to the service.

When the http request arrives to your servlet, you call a method in the service which will update ALL of its observers (every instance of your Window).

Here becomes a bit tricky. If you don't want to alert every instance of your Window, inside the http request must be present a reference to the instance to be updated. If I'm supposing right and the http message is an asynchronous response to a previous http request, you can embed in some way the Window Uuid in it to receive it back. In this way, when the observers are triggered, you can "understand" which was the initial caller.

After this you can use the `Executions.schedule` to fire your specific ZK event.

In summary:

Declare a `Observable` spring service

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl extends Observable implements MyService {

    @Override
    public void manageResponse(String response) {

      this.setChanged();
      this.notifyObservers(response);               
    }
}
```

Declare an `Observer` ZK Window (or Component, or SelectorComposer)

```
public class WndMain extends Window implements Observer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -216014257162713363L;

    private String _uuid;
    private Desktop _desktop;
    private int _notificationX;
    private MyService myService = "*Locate the service in Spring context*";


    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        this._uuid = this.getUuid();
        this._desktop = getDesktop();
        _desktop.enableServerPush(true);
        myService.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {  
        //Check which Observable notified this Observer
        if(o instanceof MyService){
            String response = (String) arg;
            if(response.equals(_uuid)){ 
                //Enter the Desktop and fire the Notification
                Executions.schedule(_desktop, new NotificationEventListener(), new Event("onHttpResponse", this, null));
            }   
        }
    }
    private class NotificationEventListener implements EventListener<Event>{

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
          if(event.getName().equals("onHttpResponse")){
                Clients.showNotification("Response arrived!", Clients.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_INFO, event.getTarget(), notificationX- 200, 0, 2000);
        }
    }

    public void onClientInfo(ClientInfoEvent event){
        this._notificationX=event.getDesktopWidth()-80;
    }
}
```

### EDIT

The `manageResponse(String response)` method is called within a JAXB REST servlet in my case:

```
@Path("myPath/servlet/response")
public class MyServiceREST {

    private MyService myService = "*Locate the service in Spring context*";


    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.WATHEVER)
    public Wathever receiveResponse(Whatever response){
        if(response!=null){     
            myService.manageResponse(response.getWindowUuid());
        return Response.status(201).build();
        }
        return Response.status(400).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have it working in one of my projects, so yes, it works... but it's not a good way to achieve your goal. The best should be an architectural rethink. The trick here is the Spring service, which is the same for every user.

Comment: I actually tried a similar approach, but instead of calling Executions.schedule, I tried calling BindUtils.postGlobalCommand and EventQueues.lookup to receive an event queue, but both failed. So I think calling Events.schedule wont work neither, but I can try...

Comment: You're right. Very nice, didn't know that. http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html#schedule%28org.zkoss.zk.ui.Desktop,%20org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener,%20T%29

Comment: don't forget to delete your observers from the observable e.g. `myService.deleteObserver(this)` on the `onClose()` method of the window!

Comment: @Jardo, calling a global command could work, if you register your viewmodels in the right scope.